# Message: Subscription validation request failed. Notification endpoint must respond with 200 OK to validation request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

i'm getting this error this is my code

```
public static async Task<ActionResult<string>> Get([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req)        {
        var graphServiceClient = GetGraphClient();

        var sub = new Microsoft.Graph.Subscription();
        sub.ChangeType = "updated";
        sub.NotificationUrl = config.ngrok+"/api/notifications";
        sub.Resource = "/users";
        sub.ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5);
        sub.ClientState = "SecretClientState";

        var newSubscription = await graphServiceClient
          .Subscriptions
          .Request()
          .AddAsync(sub);
        return $"Subscribed. Id: {newSubscription.Id}, Expiration: {newSubscription.ExpirationDateTime}";
    }
```

when subscribing i get the error, it's because of the NotificationUrl? i'm very new at this:/

Comment: Did you missed any authentication that requires to pass it as token?

Comment: The ActionResult is parsing the body of the response.  When you get an error response (not 200) the body is empty and you get an exception.  So you need to correct the request which is bad.  the server doesn't like something in the request and return an error.

Comment: No, i'm using ngrok but when i run my functions the url that throws me is local host 7071 and as i saw in the tutorial it should be 5000

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msgraph-changenotifications-trackchanges/5-exercise-change-notifications i'm following this tutorial, but is in Visual code, i'm using Visual Studio with azure functions